# How to upload universal tvOS app?

Tags: xcode, tvos

Does anyone know how to upload a tvOS that is part of a universal app in itunes connect? I have been trying for hours to get my tvOS app to upload but it is not working.

My error from Application Loader is this:

[image]

I have tried using the same provisioning profile that I did for the iOS version which did not work. Then I made a separate tvOS development provisioning profile using the same bundle ID (which is what I found out I was supposed to be doing) which gives the above error.

In iTunes Connect, I have a single app which has the iOS and tvOS versions enabled. The iOS version has uploaded successfully.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you've already uploaded a binary with that build number, `1`. You need to change your build number. For example, change it to `1.1.1`, `2`, `9823928374`, or whatever you'd like. After you've updated the build number, create a new archive and upload again.

[image]